# How to merge two sorted arrays into a sorted array but without using a third array

Tags: java

Given two sorted arrays in ascending order with one of them holding extra space to accommodate all the elements of both the arrays, merge the two sorted arrays so that the resultant array is also sorted in ascending order without creating a third array.

I pretty much wrote a program for merging but i used a third array.

Comment: Seems like you haven't put in any effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have efficiency issues, just add one array to the end of other array. Then sort this concatenated array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {    
    int a_size = a.size();
    for(int i=0; i<b.size();i++ ) {
        a[a_size]= b[i];
        a_size++;
    } 
    Arrays.sort(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be as follows.

1. Take first element from your smaller array and find its position(say it's nth position) in the bigger array.
2. now Take second element from your smaller array and find its position in the bigger array not from the beginning rather from nth position onwards.
3. now take third element from smaller array and repeat this process till your smaller array is exhausted.

**Complexity Comparison**

1.Its best case complexity is as low as size of smaller array. though worst case is size of smaller array * size of bigger array.

2.If you use utility sort methods from Collection API i.e. Collection.sort() or Arrays.sort(), their complexity comes out to be **O(nlogn)** in every case, where n= sum of size of each array.Because these methods use **merge sort**.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 3 pointers, let's say i,j and k.
'i' will point to last element of first array, 'j' will point to last element of second array and 'k' will point to last empty space of first array.
compare between elements at i and j and whichever is greater put it to k. then decrement k and, i or j(whichever element was greater). Continue this till i or j gets below 0. If i gets below 0 before j then add the remaining elements of second array in first array from start.

```
void mergeSortedArrays(int arr1[],int arr2[],int m,int n)
{
    int i,j,k;
    i=m-1;
    j=n-1;
    k=m+n-1;
    while(i>=0&&j>=0)
    {
        if(arr1[i]>arr2[j])
        arr1[k]=arr1[i--];
        else
        arr1[k]=arr2[j--];
        k--;
    }
    while(j>=0)
    arr1[k--]=arr2[j--];
}
```